# Right Loop for this exercise in Java

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

Hi guys i am learning java in order to code in Android, i got some experience in PHP, so i got assigned an exercise but cant find the right loop for it, i tried else/if, while, still cant find it, this is the exercise:

**1- prompt the user to enter number of students, it must be a number that can divide by 10 (number / 10) = 0
2- check of user input, if user input not dividable by 10 keep asking the user for input until he enter the right input**

How i code it so far, the while loop not working any ideas how to improve it or make it work?

```
package whiledowhile;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class WhileDoWhile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
     /*   int counter = 0;
        int num;
        while (counter <= 100) {
            System.out.println("Enter number");
            num = user_input.nextInt();
            counter += num; // counter = counter + num
            //counter ++ = counter =counter +1
        }

        System.out.println("Sum = "+ counter);
*/

        int count = 0;
        int num;
        System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
        num = user_input.nextInt();
        String ex;

       do {
     System.out.print("Wrong Number please enter again: " );
          num++;


    }
        while(num/10 != 0 ); 

    }
}
```

Comment: `if/else` isn't a loop.  Anything that can be done with a `while` loop can be done with a `for` loop, and anything that can be done with a `for` loop can be done with a `while` loop.  Which one you should use is a question of readability.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- I think you mean to use `%`, not `/`
- You probably want to have your data entry inside of your while loop

  ```
  while (num % 10 != 0) {
  // request user input, update num
  }
  // do something with your divisible by 10 variable
  ```

Answer (score 0):

When using a while loop, you'll want to execute some code *while* a condition is true. This code needs to go inside the `do` or `while` block. For your example, a do-while loop seems more appropriate, since you want the code to execute at least one time. Also, you'll want to use the modulo operator, `%`, inside of your while condition, not `/`. See below:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
int userInput;

do {
  // Do something
  System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
  userInput = s.nextInt();

} while(userInput % 10 != 0);
```